# Python asyncio await issue

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

After researching, I decided to use asyncio to get thousands of API requests faster.

```
async def get_marketcap(session, ticker, marketcap):
    url = "https://api.polygon.io/vX/reference/tickers/" + ticker +"&apiKey=" + profile.POLYGON_API_KEY
    async with session.get(url, ssl=False) as response:
        text = await response.json()
        marketcap[ticker] = text['results']['market_cap']

async def scan(api):
    df = pd.read_csv('./data/tickers/polygon_list.csv')

    tickers = df['ticker'].tolist()

    marketcap = {}

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [get_marketcap(session, ticker, marketcap) for ticker in tickers]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    return marketcap
```

This gets a list of stock tickers from a csv file and does about 9,000 API requests using aiohttp to get each ticker's marketcap from JSON responses.
(I set ssl=False because it was giving me an SSL error before)

```
Asyncio.run(scan(api))
```

Is called from a different python file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jakeyoon/Documents/Python Programs/Trade Bot/trader.py", line 22, in <module>
    tickers = asyncio.run(test.scan(api))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/jakeyoon/Documents/Python Programs/Trade Bot/test.py", line 25, in scan
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "/Users/jakeyoon/Documents/Python Programs/Trade Bot/test.py", line 12, in get_marketcap
    with session.get(url, ssl=False) as response:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

This is the error I get...
I also tried

```
asyncio.ensure_future()
```

And this fixed the error below but gave me a KeyError ['results'] for some reason I don't understand...
There is an attribute 'result' for sure.
I've been looking at multiple stack overflow posts, YouTube, and tutorials but still having trouble understanding what's wrong.
It seems like asyncio is being updated frequently so I'm not sure what's the best methods and practices to use.

Could you help me understand what's wrong or understand asychio concept better?
Thank you!

Comment: _there is an attribute 'result' for sure._ -- Are you sure?  Not every web request succeeds.

Comment: Yeah, you do a lot of web stuff without much of exception handling, which always leads to a failure here and there. Especially when there are _thousands of API requests_ going on.

Comment: The code shown in your stack trace is different from the code you've pasted into the question. According to the stack trace, you need to change the `with` on line 12 of `test.py` to `async with`.

Answer (score 0):

setting ssl=False was not a good fix as API seemed to change and said failed to establish SSL handshake

```
Install Certificates.command
```

did not work for me so had to copy and paste the python file and run it independently

```
# install_certifi.py
#
# sample script to install or update a set of default Root Certificates
# for the ssl module.  Uses the certificates provided by the certifi package:
#       https://pypi.python.org/pypi/certifi

import os
import os.path
import ssl
import stat
import subprocess
import sys

STAT_0o775 = ( stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR
             | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IXGRP
             | stat.S_IROTH |                stat.S_IXOTH )


def main():
    openssl_dir, openssl_cafile = os.path.split(
        ssl.get_default_verify_paths().openssl_cafile)

    print(" -- pip install --upgrade certifi")
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable,
        "-E", "-s", "-m", "pip", "install", "--upgrade", "certifi"])

    import certifi

    # change working directory to the default SSL directory
    os.chdir(openssl_dir)
    relpath_to_certifi_cafile = os.path.relpath(certifi.where())
    print(" -- removing any existing file or link")
    try:
        os.remove(openssl_cafile)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    print(" -- creating symlink to certifi certificate bundle")
    os.symlink(relpath_to_certifi_cafile, openssl_cafile)
    print(" -- setting permissions")
    os.chmod(openssl_cafile, STAT_0o775)
    print(" -- update complete")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
task = asyncio.ensure_future(get_marketcap(session, ticker, marketcap))
tasks.append(task)


Asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Also fixed the issue

Following advices from the comments,
I added try exception to catch 404 or other API errors
and my code did have async with which still gave out an error but I guess the stack trace was copied before.

Thanks!